# Handling Web Element update using Selenium-Webdriver and PhantomJS

Tags: ruby, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to implement Selenium-Webdriver for Ruby with PhantomJS for headless testing.

**Scenario:** Testing login authentication

**Steps:**  Enter Username >> Enter Password >> Click on Login >> Verify error message

**Issue:**

> 1. The 'error message' element is not containing any text. (The element does exist on page load)
> 2. Selenium-webdriver is running perfectly with FirefoxDriver, i.e., error-message is displayed and test step succeeds.
> 3. I am also capturing the screenshot at the last step. The screenshot does not show the error message for PhantomJS.

**Webdriver Config:**

```
def initialize_driver(web_url)
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, url: "http://localhost:9134"
    @wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(timeout:10)
    @driver.manage.window.maximize
    @driver.get "#{web_url}"

end
```

**PhantomJS Config:** (PhantomJS listening to port 9134)

```
$ phantomjs --webdriver=9134
```

**Script:**

```
// Find Function
def find hash
  @wait.until { @driver.find_element hash }
  @driver.find_element hash
end

// expected_value = "Invalid username or password"

// Asserting function
element = find(:id => web_element.identifier_value)
if !(element.text.eql? expected_value) then
  raise "\nAsserting - #{expected_value} failed\nFound: '#{element.text}', Expecting: '#{expected_value}'"
end
```

**Output:**

```
Asserting - Invalid username or password failed
Found: '', Expecting: 'Invalid username or password'
```

Comment: Run the test against Chrome to see, visually, what it's doing.

Comment: Ran the test using ChromeDriver. The test passed and the error message was shown on the screen.

Comment: I was fiddling with my code and I noticed that PhantomJS is not able to click on a button/link if I use 'send_keys :return' action instead of 'click'.
I replaced this call with click and voila, the error message prompt appeared.
Is this expected?